# how to redirect to a new page from a swf file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, flash

I have a swf file, which handels some xml data. After that process complets I am giving the data back to my rails server. My problem is, that any redirection in my rails app is handed ower to the swf file and the actual displayed page remains the same!

How can I perform a redirection in my webpage from a swf flash file.

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's done like this:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("home.html"));
```